# How to change value of choice field in Django shell?

Tags: python, django, shell

I have started Django in about a month ago and I am having problem in it.

I had created a model which is one to one linked with User model

This is my `models.py` file:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

# Create your models here.
class UserInfo(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    options = (('individual','Individual'),
                ('institute',"An institute"),
    )
    userAs = models.CharField(max_length=100,choices=options)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
    class Meta:
        ordering = ["user"]

@receiver(post_save,sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserInfo.objects.create(user=instance)
```

...and I want to change value of `userAs` from shell and I am unable to do it.

This is what I tried:

```
In [10]: us = User.objects.get(username="foo")

In [11]: us.userinfo.userAs
Out[11]: 'individual'

In [12]: type(us.userinfo.userAs)
Out[12]: str

In [13]: us.userinfo.userAs = 'institute'

In [14]: us.save()

In [15]: us.userinfo.userAs
Out[15]: 'institute'

In [16]: us = User.objects.get(username="steve04")

In [17]: us.userinfo.userAs
Out[17]: 'individual'
```

...but I am unable to change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Your problem

You're modifying `us.userinfo` and saving your `us` instance. However, `us` is unchanged. You modified your `userinfo` object that is inside `us`, but not `us` itself.

### Solution

You should save `us.userinfo` instead of `us`, here is a demo:

```
In [1]: us = User.objects.get(username="foo")

In [2]: us.userinfo.userAs = 'institute'

In [3]: us.userinfo.save()

In [4]: us = User.objects.get(username="steve04")

In [5]: us.userinfo.userAs
Out[5]: 'institute'
```